# Displaying pdf file stored in the server and downloading it using php

Tags: php, file, filesystems, download

I have stored .pdf, .doc, .txt files inside a directory in the web server. I am able to display all the files stored inside the directory but the download fails. Each time I click on the hyperlink sample.txt gets downloaded with blank contents. Please look into the codes and suggest me.

this is what I am using in show_directory.php

```
<?PHP
    // Define the full path to your folder from root 
    $path = "/public_html/bc/upload/"; 

    // Open the folder 
    $dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Unable to open $path"); 

    // Loop through the files 
    while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) { 

    if($file == "." || $file == ".." || $file == "download_file.php" ) 

        continue; 
        echo "<a href=\"download_file.php\">$file</a><br />"; 


    } 
    // Close 
    closedir($dir_handle); 
?>
```

The contents of download_file.php is:

```
<?PHP
//download.php
//content type
header('Content-type: text/plain');
//open/save dialog box
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sample.txt"');
//read from server and write to buffer
readfile('test.txt');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
....
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . 'test.txt' . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
readfile('test.txt');
....
```

why don't you use binary?

Comment: This doesn't help, look i have 2 files named abc.doc & xyz.pdf saved in a $path = "/public_html/bc/upload/" and i am using the loop to display both the files echo "<a href=\"download_file.php\">$file</a><br />";  The display part works properly but i am unable to download the files. After using binary as you suggested in your codes when i click on it a blank text file named test.txt is downloaded.